# Set keyboard focus to a QInputDialog with Python PySide

Tags: python, qt, keyboard, focus, pyside

I have QSystemTray which when is double clicked creates a QInputDialog box to input a text.

such as:

```
password, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(None, "Password", "Password:", QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
```

I want the focus to be set in the input dialog without forcing the user to use mouse or tab to focus.

I do know about the QWidget.setFocus() but doesnt work in my case. I have a QSystemTray with a Qmenu on right click and a default action on double click to execute something.

Thank you for your expert advice.

Comment: It should work by default. But maybe your window manager prevents the dialog window from gaining focus. If that's the case, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Thank you Pavel, I will test this on different operating system to see if the behaviour changes